# Problems while importing packages in Python

Tags: python, directory-structure, python-import

Problems while importing files from packages.

So this is my directory structure of packages:

```
appname/libs/package1/files
            /package2/files
            /package3/files
```

So, inside the directory package1, I'm not able to import package2,package3. Similar scenario in package 2 and package 3. In no scenario, I'm going through cyclic dependencies, either. Where might I be going wrong?

I'm just not able to do `from libs import package1`

`__init__.py` file is present in each directory.

Comment: Add `appname` to PYTHONPATH?

Comment: It gives no such file or directory error, even though the directory exists.

Comment: Isn't the error: "ImportError: No module named ..."?

Comment: Btw you need the absolute path of `appname` in `PYTHONPATH`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better try it as an answer:

Add `path/to/appname` to `PYTHONPATH`, so Python will know where to look for imports.

Comment: I did and got an error: no such file or directory. The directory exists. A bit clueless what's happening.

Comment: What said "no such file or directory"? And to what command? On *nix, it's `export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/appname`.